# Could not find the correct Provider above the BlocListener Widget

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to use Bloc provider for user authentication in my flutter app. When I try to access the data i'm always getting this error even though I double checked all the files.

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<StateStreamable<Object?>> above this 
BlocListener<StateStreamable<Object?>, Object?> Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
```

**main.dart:**

```
void main() async {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => AuthBloc(LoginInitState(), AuthRepository()))
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter app',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity),
        home: const LoginPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**parts from login.dart:**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    authBloc = BlocProvider.of<AuthBloc>(context);
    super.initState();
  }
```

######################################################

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
      body: BlocListener(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is UserLoginSuccessState) {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()));
          }
        },
        child: SafeArea...
```

I'm still new to flutter and struggling with the state management part, I'd be glad if anybody can help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `BlocListener` you're missing the `State` and the `Bloc`

Here's what I mean

```
BlocListener<AuthBloc, AuthState>(
        listener: (context, state) {
          if (state is UserLoginSuccessState) {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const HomeScreen()));
          }
        },
        child: SafeArea...
```

Comment: https://media.giphy.com/media/2y98KScHKeaQM/giphy.gif
It is my Ninja way